# prevent database entries rollsback incase of error in nestjs migration run

Tags: typeorm

I have written a migration in nestjs which iterates through some data in a for each loop. Each loop iterations saves entry in the database. The problem is when an error occurs, migration deletes all the entries in the database it has added. How can I prevent that? I don't want the database to roll back to the previous state but keep all the entries that have been added. I a, using `typeorm`

Comment: what about use try-catch block in the loop? or provide some code to tell more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.